Wp customizer Custom control class - get value from custom argument to enqueue function inside class
I'm working with custom control in wp customizer.
Got custom argument for this control ( foo ) and trying to get its value as a part of enqueue directory.
So, custom argument foo shows up properly in function render_content();
As I try to do the same in function foo_enqueue(); ( yeah, I know its linked with action ) its broking.
After that, even in render content - foo argument output dissapears.
Class looks like that:
class Foo_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {

 public $type = 'foo_control';  
    
 public $foo; // declare foo argument


 public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array(), $options = array() ) {
    
    parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );
        
    add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'foo_enqueue' ), 15 );                      
 }
 
 public function foo_enqueue() {
                        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foo-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    
    // $this->foo = $foo_dir;   
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/'.$foo_dir.'.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

    // js file is not loading with $foo_dir and brokes display foo at render_content after apply                    
 }

 public function render_content() {

    echo $this->label;          // Foo label
    echo $this->description;    // Foo desc

    echo $this->foo;  // foo-script                         
 }
}

And Setting with control added to $wp_customize looks like:
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_foo_control', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new Foo_Control( $wp_customize,'my_foo_control', array(
    'section'       => 'homepage',
    'label'         => 'Foo label',
    'description'   => 'Foo desc',       
    'foo'           => 'foo-script', // custom argument

) ));


Tried with $this->foo,

Tried with function a , function b($a)

Tried with function a() { b(); }

Tried with function a { $this->b();}

Tried with function a { self::b(); }


Still can't make it.

The issue is related from how the $foo argument is handled within the Foo_Control class. When we add custom arguments to a Customizer control, these arguments should be passed to the constructor and stored as class properties so we can made given changes to confirm the custom argument foo is properly utilized and does not conflict with the enqueue function.
Could you please try to replace
public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array(), $options = array() ) {
    
    parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );
        
    add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'foo_enqueue' ), 15 );                      
 }

with the given code
public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array(), $options = array() ) {
    
    parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );

    if ( isset( $args['foo'] ) ) {
        $this->foo = $args['foo']; // Here we are assigning the custom argument.
    }
        
    add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'foo_enqueue' ), 15 );                      
 }

Also please try to replace the given code
public function foo_enqueue() {
                        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foo-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    
    // $this->foo = $foo_dir;   
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/'.$foo_dir.'.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

    // js file is not loading with $foo_dir and brokes display foo at render_content after apply                    
 }

with the given one
    public function foo_enqueue() {
        // Ensure that the foo property is set before using it
        if ( ! empty( $this->foo ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $this->foo . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
        }
    }


